# Understanding precedence group's assignment in Swift 3.1

Tags: swift, swift3, operators

Swift allows to define our own precedence groups to use for our custom operators. There is one thing I struggle to understand and that is boolean `assignment` property.

From *The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.1)*:

> The assignment of a precedence group specifies the precedence of an operator when used in an operation that includes optional chaining. When set to `true`, an operator in the corresponding precedence group uses the same grouping rules during optional chaining as the assignment operators from the standard library. Otherwise, when set to `false` or omitted, operators in the precedence group follows the same optional chaining rules as operators that don’t perform assignment.

It doesn't say much about the exact behavior of `assignment` property. What is the difference between assignment and non-assignment operators in optional chaining?

I defined `++=` (behaving like `+=`) and `++` (behaving like `+`) operators along with AssignmentTesting struct for testing.

```
precedencegroup AssignmentTrue {
    assignment: true
}

precedencegroup AssignmentFalse {
    assignment: false
}

infix operator ++=: AssignmentTrue
infix operator ++: AssignmentFalse

extension Int {
    static func ++= (left: inout Int, right: Int) {
        left += right
    }

    static func ++ (left: Int, right: Int) -> Int {
        return left + right
    }
}

struct AssignmentTesting { var number = 0 }

var assignmentTesting: AssignmentTesting? = AssignmentTesting()
assignmentTesting?.number ++= 3 // assigns 0 + 3 to assignmentTesting.number
assignmentTesting!.number ++ 5 // returns 3 + 5
assignmentTesting?.number // == 3
```

How do `assignment: true` and `assignment: false` influence these behaviors? Any explanation is highly welcomed.

Answer (score 4):

Your example code well describes the difference:

```
// assigns (assignmentTesting!.number + 3) to assignmentTesting!.number when assignmentTesting != nil
// Do nothing when assignmentTesting == nil
assignmentTesting?.number ++= 3

// assigns (assignmentTesting!.number + 3) to assignmentTesting!.number when assignmentTesting != nil
// Crashing when assignmentTesting == nil
assignmentTesting!.number ++= 3

// Does not compile
//assignmentTesting?.number ++ 5

// returns (assignmentTesting!.number + 5) when assignmentTesting != nil
// Crashing when assignmentTesting == nil
assignmentTesting!.number ++ 5
```

When `++=` is an assignment operator, Optional-chaining like `assignmentTesting?.number ++= 3` works very similar to:

```
(assignmentTesting != nil) ? (assignmentTesting!.number ++= 3) as Void?  : nil
```

But when `++` is not an assignment operator, `assignmentTesting?.number ++ 5` is not a valid expression in Swift and does not work as:

```
(assignmentTesting != nil) ? (assignmentTesting!.number ++ 5) as Int? : nil
```

Comment: I still don't understand the difference. Why can't just the nature of inout parameter handle it? I found nice explanation about Swift 2.2 behavior, which is the same I guess: *"Swift 2.2 has assignment modifier that works as follows: an operator marked assignment gets folded into an optional chain, allowing `foo?.bar += 2` to work as `foo?(.bar += 2)` instead of failing to type-check as `(foo?.bar) += 2`. This behavior will be passed to assignment: true on precedence groups."*, but it's still vague to me.

Comment: It describes the syntax of declaring an assignment operator in Swift 2, and the semantics or behavior is the same in Swift 3. You may need to define other operators which uses `inout` but the behavior _Optional chaining for assignment_ is not desired.

Comment: Can you explain in details what is the difference in the optional chaining between assignment and non-assignment operators? I'm very curious why is another parameter needed just for the purpose of handling assignment in optional chaining. It must be important enough to introduce new syntax in `precedencegroup`.

Comment: @RoboRobok, Already included in my answer. Please read it carefully. Without it, how Swift compiler parse `a?.property <op> b`? It should cause error with diagnostics **The Optional value `a?.property` is not unwrapped. Do you mean `!` or `?`?** Or it should be compiled as an Optional chaining for assignment?

Comment: I read it carefully and still don't get it, sorry. Can you give an example basing on some existing operators?

Comment: @RoboRobok, there's a very good example. `a?.property <op> b` is a valid expression when `<op>` is an operator marked as `assignment`, it is not a valid expression and causes error when `<op>` is not an `assignment` operator.

Answer (score 0):

The simple explanation for the difference is that the code cannot be complied if you use unassignable operators during optional chaining.

In your example, you set `assignmentTesting?.number ++= 3` in which `++=` tries to behave the same as `+=`. However, as `assignment: false`, *operators in the precedence group follows the same optional chaining rules as operators that don’t perform assignment*. The assignment is not being performed, so the compiler complains.

Therefore, you need to  infix `++=` in the `AssignmentPrecedence` to make it assignable during optional chaining.

```
infix operator ++=: AssignmentPrecedence
```

or

```
precedencegroup AssignmentTrue {
    assignment: true
}
infix operator ++=: AssignmentTrue
```

---

**Update**

Your example is actually self-explained and you have also pointed out *an operator marked assignment gets folded into an optional chain, allowing `foo?.bar += 2` to work as `foo?(.bar += 2)` instead of failing to type-check as `(foo?.bar) += 2`. This behavior will be passed to assignment: true on precedence groups* from [SE-0077](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160620/021813.html).

- If you declare `assignmentTesting` as optional, but do not infix `++=` in the `AssignmentPrecedence` group, the compiler would take the statement as `assignmentTesting?.number += 3`. It won't know that `(assignmentTesting?.number)` will return `nil` or not. Therefore it will fail to compile.
- If you declare `assignmentTesting` as optional, and infix `++=` in the `AssignmentPrecedence` group, it allows `assignmentTesting?.number += 3` to work as `assignmentTesting?(.number += 3)` based on SE-0077. It is type checked and proven correct at compile time. The statement will pass because `number += 3` will take precedence over the optional chaining.
- If you force unwrap `assignmentTesting`, the statement would be `assignmentTesting!.number += 3`. As you are sure that `assignmentTesting` won't be `nil`, the compiler won't complain. However, if during runtime, `assignmentTesting` is unsuccessful to be unwrapped, a runtime error will be triggered.

Comment: I know all of this. Your answer doesn't explain what happens.

Comment: I had played around with your example a while and also read through the conversation between you and @OOPer before giving the answer, and thought that it would be redundant to mention, but I updated my answer anyway. Not sure why it still bother you a lot, but in case you still be, sorry, I could not help. Someone else might give better explanations.

Answer (score 0):

A binary operator, even one that does **not** perform an assignment, may be included in a precedence-group with `assignment: true`. In this case, if the left operand uses optional chaining (and does not fail because it is **nil**), the operator will act on the value hidden behind the optional. The returned result  will still be an optional.

In the case of `assignment: false`, the operator will just see the operand as an optional rather than the type of value it needs, and an error will follow.

In your code, replace the line:

```
 assignmentTesting!.number ++ 5
```

with the line:

```
assignmentTesting?.number ++ 5
```

If you set `AssignmentFalse` as the precedence-group for the operator `++`, you will get an error. If you set `AssignmentTrue`, it will work, adding 5 to the value 3 hidden behind the Optional, and return `Optional(8)`.